# Laravel 4 seeding accents

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, seeding

I'm trying to seed categories in my database. I set the title as unique. However, in french it's spelled catÉgorie.

I try to seed **Catégorie 1, Catégorie 2, Catégorie 3**. I got an error when I `php artisan db:seed` because he read it has **Cat?gorie 1, Cat?gorie 2, Cat?gorie 3** and that **Cat** is repeated (therefore not unique).

I've set my db to **utf8_general_ci** and did the change in **config/database.php**.

What did I miss here?

Comment: Please provide the errors and code. And did you check the encoding of the seeder php file?

Comment: Is your seed file saved in UTF8?

Answer (score 1):

Although you do not specify that, Im assuming you are using mysql and the "Categorie 1" is the content of some filed in one of the seeded tables. Things to remember if you want to use Laravel with utf8 mysql data: 

**Laravel 4 Config**

```
//file: app/config/database.php

'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

**Seeder files encoding**

- obviously, all your files should be saved with utf8 encoding.

**Data collation**

- the database collation is set to the utf8 you set in the above mentioned config file
- the tables collation is the same utf8
- the fields are also utf8 where needed

**Database connection**

- the connection itself should be of utf8.

Regarding the last remark, ofcourse Laravel already deals with that while establishing mysql connection by executing ["set names '$charset' collate '$collation'"](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php#L29) . If for some reason you will still be facing problems, try enforcing utf8 charset and collation in **mysql server config** and it should ultimately solve your issues:

```
//file /etc/mysql/my.cnf

[mysqld]
...
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
...
```

Answer (score 0):

### Hints & Analysis

"Cat?gorie 1" or "Catégory 1" are **processed** as normal strings being inserted in a DB Table row collumn.

But Some of the modern query strings parameters are represented by a  like

```
query("SELECT something FROM somewhere WHERE condition IN (?)", array('this', 'that'))
```

Here your query compiler may get lost if stuff is not well **formatted**.

.

**Another point is**, if you are using Artisan command line in Dos if you're on Windows for example, the output messages either mentioning success, errors or whatever will not be displayed correctly in your console, because the DOS output will not be supported by UTF-8.

---

### Solution

1 . The seeder errors may be right, check flat your Database if the records really exists.

2 . If the records doesn't exists, please attach your : migration & seed classes.